# LINQ - simple select based on value of child element

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem here which i can solve using Xpath with c#. However I am trying to do it via LINQ and i am just not able to figure out how to do it.
I have a repeating Group2 which has several child nodes. I want to select "Group2" based on the value of an element in group 2 descendants.
thx for the help in advance. here is a sample xml.

```
<Receive>
<Idoc>
    <EDI_DC40>
        <TabName>EDI_DC40</TabName>
    </EDI_DC40>
    <Group1>
        <Group2>
            <Group3>
                <SelectGroup2BasedonValueofThisNode>001</SelectGroup2BasedonValueofThisNode>
            </Group3>
        </Group2>
        <Group2>
            <Group3>
                <SelectGroup2BasedonValueofThisNode>002</SelectGroup2BasedonValueofThisNode>
            </Group3>
        </Group2>
        <Group2>
            <Group3>
                <SelectGroup2BasedonValueofThisNode>003</SelectGroup2BasedonValueofThisNode>
            </Group3>
        </Group2>
    </Group1>
</Idoc>
```

```
var _selectedGroup = document.Descendants("Group2");
```

This selects all the Group2 -- but what next i am not sure how to put the where or select.

```
var element = _cloneDocument.Descendants("Group2").Where(x => x.Value == "001");
```

well i just tried above code and it seems to work. My next question -- is this the right way to do it? Or there is another more recommended way to do this.

Comment: I dont see any Linq here...

Comment: do you have a sample of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am sorry this is my first post to stackoverflow so i didn't know i have to provide code too - pardon me. I have added some code which is working for me to get all the  Group2 nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use LINQ2XML *inside* the where delegate, like this:

```
var element = doc
    .Descendants("Group2")
    .Where
    (
        x => x.Descendants("SelectGroup2BasedonValueofThisNode").Single().Value == "001"
    )
   .Single();
```

This will give you:

```
<Group2>
  <Group3>
    <SelectGroup2BasedonValueofThisNode>001</SelectGroup2BasedonValueofThisNode>
  </Group3>
</Group2>
```

Click [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xTZyjJ) for the example on DotNetFiddle.